# Sort text file data into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a homework problem for my computer science class. A cities census data is on a text file holding records for its citizens. Each line will have four fields(age, gender, marital status, and district) of different data types separated by a comma. For example, 22, F, M, 1.

How should I approach this? My thoughts are that I should use two 1D arrays, one for age and one for district. I need to be able to later count how many people are in each district, and how many people are in different age groups for the whole city.

How do I read each line and get the info I want into each array?

edit**
This is what I've managed to do so far. I'm trying to separate my data from fields into four different arrays. This is where I'm stuck.

```
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fStream);

        string inputRecord = "";
        string[] fields;
        int[] ageData = new int[1000];
        string[] genderData = new string[1000];
        string[] maritalData = new string[1000];
        int[] districtData = new int[1000];



        inputRecord = inFile.ReadLine();
        while (inputRecord != null)
        {
            fields = inputRecord.Split(',');

            int i = 0;

            ageData[i] = int.Parse(fields[0]);
            genderData[i] = fields[1];
            maritalData[i] = fields[2];
            districtData[i] = int.Parse(fields[3]);
            i++;

            inputRecord = inFile.ReadLine();
         }
```

edit 2**

First question, I've decided to use the below code to find out how many citizens are in each district of the census data.

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 22; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < districtData.Length; y++)
                if (districtData[y] == x)
                    countDist[x]++;

        for (int x = 1; x <= 22; x++)
            Console.WriteLine("District   " + x + "   has   " + countDist[x] + "   citizens");
```

In my `.Writeline` when `x` reaches two digits it throws off my columns. How could I line up my columns better?

Second question, I am not quite sure how to go about separating the values I have in `ageData` into age groups using an if statement.

Comment: Thank you for editing my original post from a block of text into something easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like each of the four fields have something in common... they represent a person surveyed by the census.  That's a good time to use a class along the lines of

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public int District { get; set; }
}
```

Then, just read in all of the lines from the text file (if it's small, it's fine to use [File.ReadAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)), and then create an instance of Person for each line in the file.

You can create a

```
List<Person> people;
```

to hold the Person instances that you parse from the text file.

Since the lines appear to be separated by commas, have a look at [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**UPDATE**

The attempt in your edit is pretty close.  You keep creating a new `i` and initializing it to 0.  Instead, initialize it outside your loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (inputRecord != null)
{
    fields = inputRecord.Split(',');
```

Also you may want to trim excess spaces of of your input.  If the fields are separated with ", " rather than just "," you will have excess spaces in your fields.

```
        genderData[i] = fields[1].Trim();
        maritalData[i] = fields[2].Trim();
```

Comment: You can also use linq using this class structure, the linq below is a bit of an overkill though ;): List<Person> o = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TestCases\test.txt").Select(x => x.Split(',')).Select(y => new Person() { Age = int.Parse(y[0]), Gender = y[1], MaritalStatus = y[2], District = int.Parse(y[3]) }).OrderBy(y => y.Age).ToList();

Comment: Thank you for your comments to my question. We have not covered classes in class yet and your answers unfortunately are above what I understand

Comment: I honestly don't see why your professor would assign this question without having covered classes.  I guess you could solve it with one List or array per attribute, but that would be a very bad structure and would teach a bad programming habit.  What topics are you currently learning?

Comment: Just saw your edit... that's what was talking about with one array per attribute.  What problem do you see exactly?  (One problem: This will fail with more than 1000 lines in the file since your arrays are fixed at that size).

Comment: I am aware that this program will fail for more than 1000 lines. I have not decided if I should just make the number very large or if there is a better way. My concern right now is how I'm separating the data from `fields[]`. The only way I knew how to test it was a `Console.WriteLine(ageData[0]);` and then do another `Console.WriteLine(ageData[1]);` The first one displays the age of the last line of my file and the second give me a 0. So only one value is being saved into my array right now.

Comment: We have covered methods, decisions, looping, and arrays. The only things we have not gone over are file input and classes.

Comment: The "better" way is to use a `List<T>` (e.g. `List<int>` or `List<string>`) for the attributes rather than an array, since it automatically manages its own size.  The best way is to use classes, rather than separate Lists/arrays per attribute.  I'll update my answer to show what's wrong with ageData[1].

Comment: Wow, now that you pointed it out its so obvious that I was creating a new `i`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
List<string[]> o = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TestCases\test.txt").Select(x => x.Split(',')).OrderBy(y => y[0]).ToList();
```

Each person is a string array in the list. 
Each property is a index in the array eg: age is first.
The above code reads all lines comma delimits them orders them by age and adds them to the list.

Comment: Thank you for your comments to my question. We have not covered classes in class yet and your answers unfortunately are above what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class PersonsManager
{
    public static PersonStatistics LoadFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        var statistics = new PersonStatistics();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            var separators = new[] { ',' };
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    continue; //--malformed line

                var lParts = line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (lParts.Length != 4)
                    continue; //--malformed line

                var person = new Person
                {
                    Age = int.Parse(lParts[0].Trim()),
                    Gender = lParts[1].Trim(),
                    MaritalStatus = lParts[2].Trim(),
                    District = int.Parse(lParts[3].Trim())
                };

                statistics.Persons.Add(person);
            }
        }

        return statistics;
    }
}

public class PersonStatistics
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; private set; }

    public PersonStatistics()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllByGender(string gender)
    {
        return GetByPredicate(p => string.Equals(p.Gender, gender, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }

    //--NOTE: add defined queries as many as you need
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetByPredicate(Predicate<Person> predicate)
    {
        return Persons.Where(p => predicate(p)).ToArray();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public int District { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var statistics = PersonsManager.LoadFromFile(@"d:\persons.txt");
var females = statistics.GetAllByGender("F");
foreach (var p in females)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", p.Age, p.Gender, p.MaritalStatus, p.District);
}
```

I hope it helps.